# default value doesnt work in formset - django

Tags: django, default, formset, inline-formset

I'm trying to set default value for my django inline formset , but it only shows for the first form , the others are empty !

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    takes_by = models.ManyToManyField('vistors.Vistor',through='BookingVisitor',related_name='vistors')

class BookingVisitor(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey('vistors.Vistor',on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='visitor_booking')
    booking = models.ForeignKey(Booking,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='booking_bookingvisitors')
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='some text')
```

but it doesnt work !? i also tried this in my view

```
initial_data = {'reason':'some text'}
VistorsInlineFormset(prefix='formset',initial=initial_data)
```

but it raise this error :

> KeyError at /en/some/url
> 0

and this is my forms.py

```
class BookingVisitorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    visitor = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Vistor.objects.all().order_by('-pk'),empty_label='--------',

    )

    class Meta:
        model = BookingVisitor
        fields = ['visitor','reason']

VistorsInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(Booking,BookingVisitor,form=BookingVisitorForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset):

```
>>> formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[
...     {'title': 'Django is now open source',
...      'pub_date': datetime.date.today(),}
... ])
```

So your code should be:

```
initial_data = [{'reason':'some text'},] # a list
VistorsInlineFormset(prefix='formset',initial=initial_data)
```

Comment: thank you for your response , but it only works for the first form , for the other inline formsets shows a blank field

Comment: That's the point. You can add more objects in that list for the second, the third....

Comment: i did but still doesnt work `initial_data = [{'reason':'text'},{'reason':'text'}]`